# How to add a line below the company name and above the role in an Overleaf resume template?

Tags: fonts, spacing, errors, resume

I want to code a line between the company name and title in my CV on overleaf. However, anything I do completely messes up my format. Here is a picture of my current template. [image: Company name and title name] and my code is:

\resumeSubheading
{Company name}{Helsinki, Finland}
{\textit {Title name}}{\normalfont May 2021 -- Present}

```
  \begin{itemize} [noitemsep]
     \item \textit {\small \normalfont JOB DESCRIPTION ETC.}
```

What do I insert into the code so that I achieve a single line of text between the company name and title name in normal font? Example attached below.

[image: Template that I want to achieve, a line between the company name and title name]

Comment: There many CV templates on Overleaf. Which one are you using?

Comment: Hi, i'm using Jake's resume CV template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please give us a link to the used template?